# Programming for MIDI on Novation Launchpad?

Tags: midi

If I was looking to program the MIDI input (the lights) and output (the buttons) on my Novation Launchpad so that I could play around with the lights in actual coding as opposed to an audio program, what language or IDE would I need to use to do this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible; this is exactly how those audio programs were created.

You would need to use a language that can access your operation system's MIDI ports. In practice, that's all of them, so just use whatever language you're already comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project to build a Native Instruments Reaktor-like stream manipulation environment, only for javascript, that is intended for just this building exactly this kind of interaction. It's intended to allow more experienced coders to contribute small units of code and user interface to a collaborative library that non-engineers can wire together to perform tasks and control hardware.

Unfortunately, it's in the very early stages at the moment - a proof-of-concept alpha is all I've released, and it's not featured enough to be of practical use, even if you could write javascript :( However, I can already pass midi data in and out, in the manner that you would need to interact with a launchpad, 'wire' up blocks of code with cables, and includes a synth library. I'm a couple of releases away from incorporating the [Johnny-5 npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/johnny-five) which will allow it to interact with the hardware attached to Arduino's and Raspberry PIs.

It's in a very early state right now, but you can see it running in your browser here: [Midibiz](https://midibiz.firebaseapp.com/). You'll need canary chrome to run the demo and unfortunately, there's a bug that will prevent midi outputs from being wired up on the windows implementation right now :( But you should be able to get the idea from this.

Sorry not to be of more immediate help.